# Unbalanced parenthesis python

Tags: python, regex

I have the following code:

```
def commandType(self):
    import re
    print self.cmds[self.counter]
    if re.match("@",self.cmds[self.counter]):
        return Parser.A_COMMAND

    elif re.match('(',self.cmds[self.counter]):
        return Parser.L_COMMAND

    else:
        return Parser.C_COMMAND
```

and on this line: `elif re.match('(',self.cmds[self.counter]):`

I'm getting an error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe try replacing '(' with '\\(' ..Worth a shot I guess..

Comment: Some details regarding the error would have been useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Parentheses have [special meaning in regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). [You can escape the paren](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10318284/139010) but **you really do not need a regex at all for this problem**:

```
def commandType(self):
    print self.cmds[self.counter]
    if '@' in self.cmds[self.counter]):
        return Parser.A_COMMAND

    elif '(' in self.cmds[self.counter]:
        return Parser.L_COMMAND

    else:
        return Parser.C_COMMAND
```

Answer (score 8):

The parenthesis `'('` and `')'` are used as grouping mechanism and scope operators in regexps. You have to escape them (and any other control symbols) via backslash, e.g. `'\('`.

Answer (score 2):

The language of regular expressions gives a special meaning to `(` (it's used for starting a group). If you want to match a literal left-parenthesis, you need to escape it with a backslash: `elif re.match(r'\(', ...`.

(Why `r'...'` rather than just `'...'`? Because in ordinary strings, backslashes are also used for escaping control characters and suchlike, and you need to write `\\` to get a single backslash into the string. So you could instead write `elif re.match('\\(', ...`. It's better to get into the habit of using `r'...'` strings for regular expressions -- it's less error-prone.)