# Replace white space and metacharacters in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this:

```
str1 = "/path/happy (dog)"
```

for some purpose i want it like:

```
str2 = "/path/happy\ \(dog\)"
```

I tried using re:

```
str1 = "happy (dog)"
tuple_1 = ('\s+','(',')')


for i in tuple_1:

   match = re.search(r"("+i+")",str1)

   if match:
      str1 = re.sub(match.group(),"\\"+match.group(),str1)

print str1
```

But it gives error:

```
sre_constants.error: unbalanced parenthesis
```

I know i am missing something here...

Comment: You have to escape parenthesis in regex.

Comment: Have you googled your error message? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318248/unbalanced-parenthesis-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you apply the changes mentioned by the other answers (escaping the search terms in the tuple), which is valid and important, you still get a

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 6, in <module>
    str1 = re.sub(match.group(),"\\"+match.group(),str1)
error: unbalanced parenthesis
```

but this time at a different line. So when you use the [regex's sub function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub), the first parameter needs to be a valid regex. `match.group()` could be anything, and is not necessarily balanced. This is where the regex is choking. So, we can take the string from `match.group()` and [escape it](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape), so we are searching for the literal. Thereby changing the line to

```
str1 = re.sub(re.escape(match.group()),"\\"+match.group(),str1)
```

On the other hand, we could just compile the pattern once, and remember it
so

```
pattern = re.compile(r"("+i+")")
str1 = re.sub(pattern,"\\"+match.group(),str1)
```

The final code is:

```
str1 = "/path/happy (dog)"
tuple_1 = (r'\s+', r'\(', r'\)')
for i in tuple_1:
     pattern = re.compile(r"("+i+")")

     match = pattern.search(str1)

     if match:
         str1 = re.sub(pattern,"\\"+match.group(),str1)
```

str1 is now `'/path/happy\\ \\(dog\\)'`

Comment: Thanks a ton Sam . It worked perfectly. Though the output is 
'/path/happy\ \\(dog\\)' which i actually wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape any special characters like a parenthesis:

```
tuple_1 = (r'\s+', r'\(', r'\)')
```

otherwise they'll be interpreted as regular expression characters instead.

Answer (score 2):

When i is '(' the resulting regular expression would be '(()'. Two open parenthesis and one closing. Therefore the error message "unbalanced parenthesis".

You must escape the two parenthesis in tuple_1:

```
tuple_1 = (r'\s+', r'\(', r'\)')
```