# Unbalanced Parenthesis in Python re.match

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, lexical-analysis

Running into a really odd issue with using `re.match()`. Here is my code:

```
for rule in rules:
    # print (rule, ", ", item)
    if re.match(rule, item):
        tokenLine.append(self.ruleDictionary[rule])
        tokenLine.append("KNOWN")
        break
```

*BACKGROUND INFO:*

There is an external file containing the lexical rules in the format of:

```
tokenName   ::  production1  |  production2  | production3
```

`ruleDictonary` is a dictionary where productions are keys mapped to relevant `tokenName`, `rules` are the keys list of `ruleDictionary` and `item` is a string that is read. Since some productions are easily summed by a regular expression, such as `[a-z]+` or `\d+`, the dictionary keys can be a regular expression definition and that's what this loop is intended to find out.

**THE PROBLEM:**

As it currently is, I run into an `unbalanced parenthesis` error when running a sample definition file and sample input I created. However, when I uncomment the `print()` statement just before the `if` statement, it works perfectly fine. I created the `print()` statement for debugging purposes and didn't realize it would make a difference in the actual execution of the program. I'm completely lost and have no idea why it works when printing is enabled.

Comment: Humour me for a moment, and run the re.match(rule, item): if statement as a tuple, eg 
re.match((rule, item)):

Comment: @KyleM Interesting, there's a different error now: `match() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'`

Comment: Could you show us the whole code, or at the very least the whole error message?

Comment: @Andrew, that shows us that somewhere you are not escaping correctly, and are thus missing a parenthesis (as a tuple requires two positional arguments)

Kuhess' solution will work for you below.

Comment: @KyleM That is the problem, I realized that was pretty stupid of me. I don't understand why it worked with a print statement just before it, though.

Comment: @Andrew, you escaped the rule in your print statement! Try doing the print statement, but not using the rule variable and see.

Comment: @KyleM what exactly do you mean by that? Are you saying his `print` statement modified `rule` as a side effect?

Comment: @LukasGraf, it didn't modify rule so much as not require the parenthesis to be escaped, after using it once the script then assumes it is escaped already. Try it, don't print rule first, simply run a print statement, and it won't escape the rule...

Comment: @KyleM "the script assumes"? That doesn't make sense, and I can't actually reproduce that. See http://ideone.com/hdQvBL

Comment: @LukasGraf, I was simplifying my response, apologies. I cannot reproduce this through my interpreter either, however I believe it is because the join statement in the print command escapes the rule.

Comment: @KyleM join statement? Those are simply three positional arguments to the `print()` function, there is no joining happening. And if so, that *would* mean that `rule` was being modified by `print()` - I'm having a hard time believing that.

Comment: @KyleM don't get me wrong, I'm not trying to get on your case here, but the behavior that @Andrew describes goes against everything I know about Python, and I therefore find it intriguing. Currently my best hypothesis is that he got a bit confused and actually changed something else besides unommenting ` # print`, but then again he seems to be pretty methodical in his approach, and not one to just post a wild assumption without verifying it a couple times.

Comment: @LukasGraf, I don't think you are on my case at all, by "join" statement I mean where it converts the object into a string representation, then joins it with the rest of the string to print (obj1, ", ", obj2) as print does behind the scenes. It is very intriguing, hence why I'd like OP to retry and exclude the rule component from his print statement!

Comment: I vote the close this question, since the problem described is not reproducible, and it doesn't help anyone but the question author.

Comment: I'd **love** to see a short sample of the input files so I can try to reproduce this problem!

Comment: @LukasGraf There actually wasn't anything changed other than that single `print()` statement. That's what was throwing me off about the problem.

Comment: @PM2Ring Done: https://github.com/x2adrew/lexical_python - the code itself is modified to handle the issue described here so the error won't occur anymore, but the sample definitions file and the sample input are exactly the same as the ones that produced the above issue. Please excuse the hack workaround if you dig through the code, this was a project I was putting together really quick and couldn't come up with a more immediate elegant solution. I'm also a student, if that gets me any fewer lashings for any obvious code mistakes I've made.

Comment: @KyleM I'll see if I can revert the code to how it was previously and exclude the join to see if that makes a difference. I'll report back with the results. Sorry for the delay, I went out for the rest of the day after I made a hack fix to deal with that.

Comment: @LukasGraf Just discovered something interesting, this might actually have something to do with the terminal. I'm working in a Windows 7 environment and was running into the bizarre scenario of it working with the `print()` statement in the command prompt. However, I just ran it in the Git Bash terminal and it behaved as expected - it terminated because of unbalanced parenthesis. I've uploaded a screenshot of the two terminals side-by-side with before and after input file is selected (where the `print()` is executed): http://imgur.com/1XnSoI5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem comes from the content of the pattern variable `rule`. It must contain a parenthesis. But in regular expressions, parentheses have a special meaning (groups).

So you need to escape them with `\(` or `\)`. You can do it with:

```
rule.replace('(', '\(')
rule.replace(')', '\)')
```

If you want to know more, there are additional information in the question [Unbalanced parenthesis python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318248/unbalanced-parenthesis-python).

Comment: I just realized how stupid that was, thank you so much!

Comment: P.S. Any idea why it works with the print statement, though? The regular expression runs fine if I print just before it.

Comment: Nope, I don't get either why the `print` can change the behaviour of the `re.match`.

Comment: @Andrew, you escaped the rule in your print statement! Try doing the print statement, but not using the rule variable and see

Answer (score 2):

As described in @Kuhess' answer, your immediate problem was that you were having rules that contained paranthesis and used them as regular expressions, but didn't escape the paranthesis (or other characters with special meaning in regular expressions like `*`).

However, that still didn't explain the behavior you observed that adding a `print()` call before trying to match the rule seemed to solve the problem.

I was able to reproduce the `unmatched paranthesis` error with the [`unmatched` branch](https://github.com/x2adrew/lexical_python/tree/unmatched) from your repo. And then, without changing a single thing, a second run with exactly the same parameters worked!

So I had closer look at your code, and I'm pretty sure I know the reason why your code is non-deterministic: You use a **dictionary** ([`self.ruleDictionary`](https://github.com/x2adrew/lexical_python/blob/unmatched/lex.py#L26)) to store the rules, [iterate over its keys](https://github.com/x2adrew/lexical_python/blob/unmatched/lex.py#L77), and `break` the loop as soon as a rule matches.

Dictionaries don't have a guaranteed order in Python. [Their order isn't arbitrary](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4Kc8xzcA68), but it's nearly impossible to predict, and it may change between subsequent runs or even just after modifing the dictionary. Therefore in some runs, the problematic rules never get tested, because one that is a valid regular expression matches, and you `break` out of the `for` loop.

So, you can't, and never should, rely on a particular order of a dictionary. So what are your options?

**1)** Use an ordered dict *(Python 2.7+)*

You could make your `rulesDictionary` an instance of [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). An `OrderedDict` will retain the items in exactly the order they were inserted:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
# ...
self.rulesDictionary = OrderedDict()
```

**2)** Dynamically sort the dictionary items by key, and iterate over that ordered sequence:

```
for key, value in sorted(dct.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]):
    # ...
```

This would give you a *stable* alphabetical order, but not the order in which the items were inserted. I do believe the order of those rules is relevant in your case, so you should go with 1).

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you! I knew that dictionaries are unordered and I overlooked that when trying to debug this and understand why it worked with the `print()` statement. It took a couple dozen tries to get it to output the `unmatched parenthesis` error with the `print()` statement in Command Prompt, but it seems to output the error every time in Git Bash, I found that interesting. Regardless, thank you for the `collections.OrderedDirect` info, I don't know much about Python collections and will spend some time getting to know more.

Comment: I was also intrigued, but not as dedicated. Your research endeavor is definitely worth an up-vote by my book!