# Finding brackets in strings python

Tags: python, regex, string

Here there

I currently have a string as follows

```
location1
      {
        type uniform;
        axis y;
        start (1000 -300 0.05 );
        end   (1000 9 0.05 );
        nPoints 3000;
      }
```

and I called it locationString.

I am trying to find all indexes for all the brackets (both '(' & ')') inside this string as follows

```
 import re
 kwSe='('
 kwEe=')'
 kwS=[match.start() for match in re.finditer(kwSe,str(locationString))]
 kwE=[match.start() for match in re.finditer(kwEe,str(locationString))]
```

but it doesnot work, can anyone help?

Comment: Please include the error message in your question... and also google the error message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unbalanced parenthesis python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318248/unbalanced-parenthesis-python)

Comment: Is there no Python package to parse your file format?

Answer (score 1):

[`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) accepts regex pattern, and [parentheses have special meaning](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) in regex (they form groups). If you want to match literal `(` and `)` you have be escape them (like `\(` and `\)`), or enclose them in character class (like `[(]` and `[)]`).

```
import re
kwSe='\('
kwEe='\)'
kwS=[match.start() for match in re.finditer(kwSe,str(locationString))]
kwE=[match.start() for match in re.finditer(kwEe,str(locationString))]
```

Comment: @ZhifangHu, if this answer solved you problem, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thanks.