# Python: Seeing error, "unbalanced parenthesis," that I don't understand

Tags: python

I'm going through Automate the Boring Stuff, and I'm working with regex to write a program that will find all phone numbers and email addresses. I've come across an error that I don't understand. I've displayed the code below, and my error underneath that. I'm sorry if the question is a little vague, I dont even know what to ask, I'm just really confused. I really appreciate any help you can give. Thanks so much!

```
#! python3
# phoneAndEmail.py - Finds phone numbers and email addresses on the clipboard.
import pyperclip, re
phoneRegex = re.compile(r'''(
(\(\d{3}\)|d{3}))?                
(\s|-|\.)                       
(\d{3})                         
(\s|-|\.)                       
(\d{4})                         
(\s*(ext|x|ext.)\s*(\d{2,5}))?  
)''', re.VERBOSE)

emailRegex = re.compile(r'''(
[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+ 
@                 
[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+ 
(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})  
)''', re.verbose)

# Find matches in clipboard text.
text = str(pyperclip.paste())
matches = []

for groups in phoneRegex.findall(text):
    phoneNum = '-'.join(group[1], groups[3], groups[5])
    if groups[8] != '':
        phoneNum += " x" + groups[8]
    matches.append(phoneNum)
for groups in emailRegex.findall(text):
    matches.append(groups[0])
```

And I got this response:

````
   File "c:\users\owner\documents\python\phoneregex.py", line 11, in <module>
     )''', re.VERBOSE)
   File "re.py", line 233, in compile
   File "re.py", line 301, in _compile
   File "sre_compile.py", line 562, in compile
   File "sre_parse.py", line 869, in parse
   sre_constants.error: unbalanced parenthesis at position 88 (line 8, column1)```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unbalanced parenthesis python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318248/unbalanced-parenthesis-python)

Comment: shouldn't it be `(\(\d{3}\)|d{3})? `

Comment: @pasbi no, man. He's trying to find what's causing the error. He has one too many closing `)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an unbalanced parentheses. Also, `re` module has method `re.VERBOSE`, not `re.verbose` Here is edited script:

```
#! python3
# phoneAndEmail.py - Finds phone numbers and email addresses on the clipboard.
import pyperclip, re
# error was below
phoneRegex = re.compile(r'''(
((\(\d{3}\)|\d{3}))?              
(\s|-|\.)                       
(\d{3})                         
(\s|-|\.)                       
(\d{4})                         
(\s*(ext|x|ext.)\s*(\d{2,5}))?  
)''', re.VERBOSE)

emailRegex = re.compile(r'''(
[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+ 
@                 
[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+ 
(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})  
)''', re.VERBOSE) # another error was here

# Find matches in clipboard text.
text = str(pyperclip.paste())
matches = []

for groups in phoneRegex.findall(text):
    phoneNum = '-'.join(group[1], groups[3], groups[5])
    if groups[8] != '':
        phoneNum += " x" + groups[8]
    matches.append(phoneNum)
for groups in emailRegex.findall(text):
    matches.append(groups[0])
```

Comment: The error was indeed there but I think `d{3}` should be `\d{3}` on that line

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked! I really appreciate it!

Comment: @edj1225 Good! If my solution worked, please, mark it as solved by clicking green checkmark near question upvote button :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this line `(\(\d{3}\)|d{3}))?` may be the problem. Not sure what the regex is trying to do, but this line seems to have an extra unpaired closing parentheses.