# Unbalanced Parenthesis in regex while finding sub string

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use regex while finding substring with incomplete words in string

```
str1 = "a) John is working in Microsoft"

str2 = "a) John is wor"
```

Expected answer : `"a) John is working"`

I tried simple regex : `re.findall(r"(\S*" + str2+ r"\S*)", str1)`

But its giving error `Unbalanced Parenthesis`

Can someone help?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318248/unbalanced-parenthesis-python)

Comment: `re.findall(r"(\S*" + re.escape(str2)+ r"\S*)", str1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here likely is the `)` in the `str2` string.  You may wrap `str2` with `re.escape` to get around this problem:

```
str1 = "a) John is working in Microsoft"
str2 = "a) John is wor"
matches = re.findall(r'(\S*' + re.escape(str2) + r'\S*)', str1)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['a) John is working']
```

Note: You appear to have swapped `str1` and `str2` in your original question, so I fixed that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
str1 = "a) John is working in Microsoft"
str2 = "a) John is wor"

if str1.startswith(str2):
    print(str2 + str1[len(str2):].split(" ")[0])

else:
    print("it doesn't go")
```

This is what it prints.

```
a) John is working
```